# How to to add the Purchase Order Number next to the normal Magento order id on all email templates

Tags: email, email-templates, magento2.3.5-p2

How to to add the Purchase Order Number next to the normal Magento order id on all sales email templates as well.

I try this but not working any idea for that invoice mail templaes

Please check screen sort.

[image]

> app/code/vendor/module/etc/di.xml

```
<preference type="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\InvoiceSender" for="vendor\module\Model\Order\Email\Sender\InvoiceSender" />
```

> app/code/vendor/module/Model/Order/Email/Sender/InvoiceSender.php

```
'purchase_order_number' => $order->getPayment()->getPoNumber(),
```

> app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/email/invoice_new.html

```
<h1{{trans 'Po Number'}}&nbsp;{{var purchase_order_number|raw}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: Answer is Related to magento 2.3.x

**Step 1. Create di.xml**

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

add below code in di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilder" type="Vendor\Module\Rewrite\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilder" />
</config>
```

**Step 2. Create SenderBuilder.php**

```
/app/code/Vendor/Module/Rewrite/Sales/Model/Order/Email/SenderBuilder.php


<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Rewrite\Sales\Model\Order\Email;
class SenderBuilder extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilder
{
    
    

    protected function configureEmailTemplate()
    {   
        
        $getTemplateVars = $this->templateContainer->getTemplateVars();
        $getTemplateVars['custom_variable_add'] = 'Custom Variable Text';    
        $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($this->templateContainer->getTemplateId());             
        $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateOptions($this->templateContainer->getTemplateOptions());
        $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateVars($getTemplateVars);
        $this->transportBuilder->setFromByScope(
            $this->identityContainer->getEmailIdentity(),
            $this->identityContainer->getStore()->getId()
        );      
    }
}
```

in email template add variable

"var custom_variable_add":"Custom Variable"

and use like

{{trans 'Order total: %custom_variable_add' custom_variable_add=$custom_variable_add|raw}}

accept solution if works for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. You mixed "type" and "for" in your preference. It should be:

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\InvoiceSender" 
            type="vendor\module\Model\Order\Email\Sender\InvoiceSender" />
```

2. Also, to override an e-mail template you need to copy the file to the theme (not module) - see: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html
3. If you must override it in a module, you have to create `etc/email_templates.xml` file in your module with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="sales_email_invoice_template" file="your_template_name.html" module="Vendor_Module"/>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

> app/design/frontend/Vendorname/ThemeName/Magento_sales/email/invoice_new.html

```
{{depend order.getPayment().getPoNumber()}}

  <h1>{{trans 'Po Number #'}} &nbsp;{{var order.getPayment().getPoNumber()|raw}}</h1>

{{/depend}}
```